# Square circles: expected value of the largest radius in a grid

Tags: probability, geometry

(Note: inspired by [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w23/challenges/lighthouse) problem, but the question asked here is unrelated).

Define a "square circle" $(h,k,r)$ to be the set of all integer points with Euclidean distance $\leq r$ from the point $(h,k)$.

If we have an $n \times n$ grid and randomly mark each point as "obstructed" or "non-obstructed" with equal probability, what is the expected value of the radius of the largest square circle we can construct in the grid with no points of the circle obstructed (the circle must be completely within the grid)?

I was able to bruteforce some small values: $E(1) = 0/2^{1^2}, E(2) = 0/2^{2^2}, E(3) = 16/2^{3^2}, E(4) = 6896/2^{4^2}, E(5) \approx 7*10^6 / 2^{5^2}$. I believe that the expected value converges to $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.